# Sorting Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a file consisting of lines such as:

`1344447216 | 1 1:0.0285122882546 2:0.0 3:0.0 4:0.152738110021 5:0.49199231262`

I want to read the file line by line into an array and sort that array with respect to the first value, which is a 'long' representation of a time stamp. How can I quickly achieve this in Python?

Comment: How quick are you to post your try?

Comment: Including your attempts at solving the issue will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Check for `key functions` at https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split on the `|` delimiter and convert the timestamp to an int.  Create a list of (timestamp, line) tuples and do a regular `list.sort()`, it will sort based on timestamp because it's the first item in the tuple.

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    array = []
    for line in f:
        timestamp = int(line.split('|')[0].strip())
        array.append((timestamp, line))

array.sort()
```